# select single value from linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008

I Have a dataTable called ***dt*** that filled from Database. the SQL Command is:

```
SELECT s.keyName,s.value FROM setting as s
```

after I fill dataTable I want to select a single value from filled ***dt***. So I tried to do some linq that here I show:

```
if (dtSetting.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
      var r1 = (from r in dtSetting.AsEnumerable()
       where r.Field<string>("keyName") == "logoName"
       select r.Field<string>("value"));

       MessageBox.Show(r1.ToString());
  }
```

but I can't see the value of s.value and r1.show says that

> system.data.enumerableRowCollection`1[system.String]

How can I implement this code to get a real value of the specific column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

r1 variable is IEnumarable, so you can get the value by applying index . You can use `First()` and `ElementAt()` too.

```
 if (r1.Count() > 0)
    MessageBox.Show(r1.ToList()[0].ToString());
    //MessageBox.Show(r1.First());
    //MessageBox.Show(r1.ElementAt(0));
```

Comment: You can't use an index on IEnumerable. First casting it to a List would work.

Comment: `ElementAt()` would also be possible

Comment: Thanks, both @Carra and you. I choose your answer because of your better answer. Thanks a lot you saved my time.

Answer (score 4):

Your r1 is an IEnumerable < string >. You should select an item from it.

Example:

```
   MessageBox.Show(r1.First());
```